# GIT via OpenSSH in Powershell is fine, so why can't I connect in plain cmd console?

Tags: git, powershell, openssh, cmd.exe, tortoise-git

when I run

```
ssh user@servername01
```

...under powershell it connects without a problem, however when I run the same command under a standard cmd prompt I am prompted for a password (no password is set on the account).

```
user@servername01's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**More details...**

I'm hoping that solving the above will help resolve some git related issues I'm having.

Again, in powershell pulling from my ssh repo as below is fine...

```
@git pull user@servername01:git/repo.git
```

but the same in console fails with

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

and also my tortoise-git fails with the same message, which is the crux of my problem as it means I can't roll git out to my devs.

Help :(

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!

My `.ssh\config` file was referencing the identity file (ssh private key) with a home-path, I changed this to an absolute path and both console and tortoise-git both started working :)

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

changed to

```
IdentityFile C:\Users\user.name\.ssh\id_rsa
```